# Issues publishing to Git with Bootstrap Theme

Tags: github

I purchased a theme from Bootstrap and when I went to publish to GitHub, I get the below error:

Your site is having problems building: The variable 
`{{!-- ## owl.lazyload.js LazyLoad require class="owl-lazy"` and link to image inside data: `data-src="url_to_img"` or/and `data-src-retina="url_to_highres_img"`. There is also option to load images into background but this needs to be tested. [See demo](/demos/demo.html)

Usage:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({ lazyLoad:true }
```

on line 35 in assets/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.0/docs_src/templates/pages/docs/dev-buildin-plugins.hbs was not properly closed with `}}`.

The builder of the theme said to remove any files not needed.  I did that but then only the repository name showed up.  Rookie errors I'm sure but just not experienced enough to know what to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I went to publish to GitHub" 
how you are trying to do that?

Comment: Please format code with grave quotes so it's more readable, and include the commands you used to try to "publish to GitHub".

Comment: I pushed the code up to the repo, then I went to settings/GitHubpages/Source/masterbranch

Comment: Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the master branch. Learn more.

 when i did that, the error came up.